# VuGen: Encountering Error: Requested form not found in extended replay, but not in standard replay

Tags: c, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I'm scratching my head at this.

I have a web/html protocol script that I created in VuGen. I correlated everything that I think needs to be correlated. When I replay the script with no log, standard log, or log with parameter substitution, the script passes and everything is successful (more or less).

When I enable extended log with "data returned from server" and replay, a web_submit_form constantly fails with the message "Error -27979: Requested form not found". I don't understand why this is happening -- it ONLY happens when I am trying to get an extended log with data. I am only using one user and one iteration with replay. I can give more details if needed.

Additional: I have increased all of the timeout settings to 700ms to ensure that enough time is given for the extended log but I'm still seeing the error.

Comment: Please indicate whether you are affirmatively checking for the positive expected result on each test step and branching your test code when and if the positive expected result from the step is not returned.   Timeout is related to the server wait time without a response and it is unlikely you will be able to modify this setting on all of your clients.

Comment: @JamesPulley Yes, I am checking if the step has passed. I am not changing the code between tests so I am not branching -- if that's what you mean. I am simply enabling or disabling extended logs.

Comment: If you are not branching within your code to exit the virtual user when the expected result does not appear then you are not checking appropriately for expected results.

Comment: @JamesPulley Can you elaborate on what you mean, then? I don't know what you mean by branching. The script fails on extended log... it returns an error and stops executing.

Comment: PCODE: if ( my expected result does not appear ) then { clean up anything I need to do in this iteration; cleanly return application to the state at the beginning of the business process; exit the iteration; }